# John Wick 2 shotgun jam in catacombs

Tags: john-wick-chapter-2, production-mistakes

At a certain point in *John Wick 2* during the catacombs scene in Italy, Wick's shotgun jams and he has to eject the shell. However, prior to the jam, there is clearly something red hanging off the shotgun that looks like a shell for several cut-scenes.

Was this a production sequencing mistake and the jammed shell was already 'stuck' in there so that he just had to rack it out? Not sure how difficult it is to intentionally stage a jammed shell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MovieDetails/comments/6l20vl/in_john_wick_2_johns_shotgun_has_a_cartridge/), the red thing you see there is indeed an extra round for the shotgun, **however**, it is not the one that jammed the gun.  That shell is deliberately clipped onto the side of the gun, near the receiver, so that he can quickly load a single shot directly into the gun. (Which is exactly what he does in the gif in that reddit post, if you watch closely.)

The clearest images I could find to illustrate how the shell is stored are actually from action figures based on the movie, like so:

[image]

(I'll admit I'm not sure how beneficial that is, except in an "oh shit I'm empty!" situation, and given Mr Wick has a proven affinity for counting shots fired, I doubt he's in that situation very often.  Then again, never hurts to have one more ;) )

Comment: Guess my confusion revolved around the presumption it didn't seem that useful. Thanks, now I can go on thinking John Wick is for real.

Answer (score 5):

Just to confirm Steve-O's answer.

The Internet Movie Firearms Database ([**IMFDB**](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Main_Page)) has a wealth of information on all types of weaponry used in movies.

> John uses a Benelli M4 Super 90 during the fight in the catacombs. It is fitted with a fixed stock and customized by TTI. When he shoots it for the first time, he fires 11 rounds before reloading; this would be only possible with an extended tube capacity of 9+1 shells and by having ghost loaded an 11th shell.

[image]

> Taran Tactical Innovations M4 Upgrade Package Benelli M4